# What creature am I?

Tags: riddle, wordplay

> They call me fruit.
>   They call me fish.
>   They call me insect.
>   They call me reptile.
>   But actually I'm not one of those.

**What creature am I ?**

Comment: @Scott I added that comment only after the answer is posted and accepted.

Comment: @Scott Ok I deleted mine, but see the comment thread below the answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are a

> **Dragon**

*They call me fruit.

They call me fish.

They call me insect.

They call me reptile.

But actually I'm not one of those.*

> The [Dragon Fruit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pitaya)
> The [Dragonfish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stomiidae)
> The [Dragonfly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragonfly)
> The [Komodo Dragon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Komodo_dragon)

***What creature am I?***

> **A [Dragon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon)** - a large fire-breathing mythical creature with wings scales, a tail and who usually guards a large treasure trove
> Some good examples of [Smaug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smaug), the dragon from [the Hobbit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hobbit):
> [image: smaug]
> [image]

Comment: and the komodo dragon (reptile)

Comment: no problem ^^  it was an easy question but saw it later than you heheh

Comment: Both of you are right, I first think as komodo, but after googling, yes there is also dragon snake (Xenodermus).

Comment: but as the question say "But actually I'm not one of those.", is wrong. if a dragon exist, it would be a reptile, wouldnt it?

Comment: @lois6b Right point. OP should have used snake instead of reptile.

Comment: @lois6b I think no, because real dragon do not exist, so we cannot say it as reptile.

Comment: @JamalSenjaya your question say "what species i am". Dragons do not exist, thats why i said "if a dragon exist".

Comment: @lois6b Ok, I have edit the question, replace species into creature. Dragon has wings, reptile do not have wings.

Comment: @JamalSenjaya, and snakes do not have legs and are reptiles. bats are not mamals cause they have wings?